# Non predefined multiple light sources in OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, glsl

There is a great article about multiple light sources in GLSL
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GLSL_Programming/GLUT/Multiple_Lights
But **light0** and **light1** parameters described in shader code, what if must draw flare gun shots, e.g every flare has it own position, color and must illuminate surroundings. How we manage other objects shader to deal with unknown (well there is a limit to max flares on the screen) position, colors of flares? For example there will be 8 max flares on screen, what i must to pass 8*2 uniforms, even if they not exist at this time?
Or imagine you making level editor, user can place lamps, how other objects will "know" about new light source and render then new lamp has been added?
I think there must be clever solution, but i can't find one.

Comment: Fixed tags and title, was in hurry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lighting equations usually rely on additive colour. So the output is the colour of light one plus the colour of light two plus the colour of light three, etc.

One of the in-framebuffer blending modes offered by OpenGL is additive blending. So the colour output of anything new that you draw will be added to whatever is already in the buffer.

The most naive solution is therefore to write your shader to do exactly one light. If you have multiple lights, draw the scene that many times, each time with a different nominated line. It's an example of [multipass rendering](http://www.excamera.com/articles/1/index.html).

Better solutions involve writing shaders to do two, four, eight or whatever lights at once, doing, say, 15 lights as an 8-light draw then a 4-light draw then a 2-light draw then a 1-light draw, and including only geometry within reach of each light when you do that pass. Which tends to mean finding intelligent ways to group lights by locality.

EDIT: with a little more thought, I should add that there's another option in [deferred shading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deferred_shading), though it's not completely useful on most GL ES devices at the moment due to the limited options for output buffers.

Suppose theoretically you could render your geometry exactly once and store whatever you wanted per pixel. So you wouldn't just output a colour, you'd output, say, a position in 3d space, a normal, a diffuse colour, a specular colour and a specular exponent. Those would then all be in a per-pixel buffer.

You could then render each light by (i) working out the maximum possible space it can occupy when projected onto the screen (so, a 2d rectangle that relates directly to pixels); and (ii) rendering the light as a single quad of that size, for each pixel reading the relevant values from the buffer you just set up and outputting an appropriately lit colour.

Then you'd do all the actual geometry in your scene only exactly once, and each additional light would cost at most a single, full-screen quad.

In practice you can't really do that because the output buffers you tend to be able to use in ES provide too little storage. But what you can usually do is render to a 32bit colour buffer with an attached depth buffer. So you can just store depth in the depth buffer and work out world (x, y, z) from that plus the [uniform] position of the camera in the light shader. You could store 8-bit versions of normal x and y in the colour buffer so as to spend 16 bits and work out z in the colour buffer because you know that the normal is always of unit length. Then, to pick a concrete example at random, maybe you could store a 16-bit version of the diffuse colour in the remaining space, possibly in YCrCb with extra storage for Y.

The main disadvantage is that hardware antialiasing then doesn't due to much the same sort of concerns as transparency and depth buffers. But if you get to the point where you save dramatically on lighting it might still make sense to do manual antialiasing by rendering a large version of the scene and then scaling it down in a final pass.